# Can't link files with database (phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, database

Task: linking the new PDF's with the websites database (phpmyadmin)
link: http://thepeninsulaqatar.com/pdf/the-peninsula-newspaper?page=57
Explanation: I am uploading all the old PDFs to the website's Upload folder (in the httpdocs directory)

**Obstacle:** How to link all the uploaded PDFs with the phpmyadmin database.

I can always supply any additional information, since I can't really locate the problem from the tables.

**What's meant by linking:** So I mean here that after uploading the PDFs on their designated folder that are already names on the database, the database automatically auto-detects and when you press the button it prompts you to download the PDFs as in page one from the website I sent. 
**What I mean by phpmyadmin:** MySQL database I guess. It's embedded at most web hosting servers.

Comment: What do you mean by "phpmyadmin database" ? What do you mean by "link with it"?

Comment: OK, a good progress. One more question: there appears to be a miss understanding here: a database is something passive. It cannot auto detect anything, it cannot show a button or prompt you for anything. A database is just data. not more, not less. So you probably you mean some php script that does all that?

Comment: Yes thanks for clarifying, sorry for missing this point.

Comment: All fine, just helping to make clear what you actually ask :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy and short answer to this. Three general approaches come into mind. None is better than the other, it depends on your situation which you prefer:

1. auto detection: 
   you need some form of script that runs periodically and scans for new files. This is typically done by a cron job, but that again is typically not offered for typical low budget web space. An alternative would be what is called a "poor mans cron" approach. Works, but annoying and complex.
2. registering during the upload: 
   a file upload typically is implemented in a script accepting and storing the file. The straight forward approach would be to enhance that script to also register the uploaded file inside the database. This is easy to implement, but you need to modify the existing script.
3. live scanning the file system: 
   instead of registering the uploaded files in some database you could also simply live scan the file system each time you want to offer a selection of a file. This obviously is slower than a database query, but it saves you from having to register the files at all, so far easier to implement. And it is very robust, since you have a single point of truth about what files exist under what name and url.

None of the approaches is trivial, but this certainly is not voodoo magic. It's impossible to give final script snippets here, the current state of the question does not offer enough information for this. Especially the existing situation, so existing scripts are missing.